# JavaScript Button Action in External File

Tags: javascript, function, html

I have my Javascript in an external script that I want to happen when a text field is filled with text and then the enter button is pressed. Can someone please explain how to get this working as nothing is happening right now when I press the enter button. Thanks for your help in advance.

Also how can I pass the text from the text box to the javascript function.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html>
  <head> 
        <title> All About Resistors </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resistorpagestlying.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript"
  src="Value_to_Color.js">
  </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

 <body>

 <p>Resistor Value: <input type="text" onClick="print_text" id="test" value="Ohms"></p>
 <button>Show Color Code</button>


  </body>
  </html>
```

This is the text in the javascript file

```
function print_text(){
document.writeln("<b>Bold Hello World via an external js file!</b>"); 
}
```

Comment: onClick="print_text" ..?

Comment: this function is defined in the **java file**? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @sasi Is that not the correct way to call a javascript function in an external file?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different programming languages. All your code is JavaScript, there is no sign of any Java there.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev It is not working for me. I am not sure that I am calling it correctly.

Comment: @Quentin My bad I will edit the post everything is in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to call a function is:

```
 function_name()
```

You are missing the parens.

Thus:

```
print_text()
```

---

If you want the function to fire when a particular key is pressed, then you also don't want to be using **click** as that will fire when the element is clicked.

You need to use the `keypress` event, and to test which key was pressed when you do so.

I've no idea how to find out what key was pressed in an `onkeypress` attribute as I don't use intrinsic event attributes. So let's move to `addEventListener`.

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="Ohms">
<script>
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
      var charCode = (typeof event.which == "number") ? event.which : event.keyCode
      if (charCode === 13) { // 13 is Enter
         print_text(); 
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now when I click on the text box it calls the function and prints in a separate page. How would I modify this so that it only called the function when the button was pressed and (less important) does not open a separate page, but instead prints the text in the current page?

Comment: If you want it to fire when the button is pressed then you'll need to bind a click event to the button, not to the text input.

Comment: The W3C has [a guide to manipulating an existing HTML document with JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<p>Resistor Value: <input type="text" onkeypress="print_text();" id="test" value="Ohms"></p>
```

Notice that `print_text()` has `()` since this is a function you are calling. Secondly, if you want to call the function when you press Enter, you need to change the body of the function to:

```
function print_text()
{
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) //enter key?
       document.writeln('<b>Bold Hello World via an external js file!</b>');
}
```

And instead of listening for "onclick" event, you need to listen for "onkeypress" events on the text field.

JsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YpVEQ/1/

Comment: Any thoughts about how to connect this to a button, so that when the button is pressed it takes the text field value and passes it to the function? Thanks for your help.